# Convert factor variable minute:second to numerical variable minute.seconds in R

Tags: r, number-formatting

I am struggling with a data frame I have been given:

```
 game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
1           95:09                46:04                 49:05
2           95:09                46:04                 49:05
3           95:31                46:07                 49:23
4           95:31                46:07                 49:23
5           95:39                46:08                 49:31
```

Currently, these columns are currently factor variables (see str output)

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ game.time.total      : Factor w/ 29 levels "100:22","100:53",..: 7 7 10 10 12
 $ game.time.first.half : Factor w/ 27 levels "45:18","46:00",..: 3 3 5 5 6
 $ game.time.second.half: Factor w/ 29 levels "48:01","48:03",..: 12 12 15 15 17
```

However I wish to be able to average each column using colmeans(). From my understanding I need to convert the column to numeric and to be expressed as minutes.seconds as shown here:

```
game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
1           95.09                46.04                 49.05
2           95.09                46.04                 49.05
3           95.31                46.07                 49.23
4           95.31                46.07                 49.23
5           95.39                46.08                 49.31
```

I understand that I could just type them out however there are many more column and rows of similar formatting...Is there a simple way of how to do this? Or do I need to re-adjust the format of the original file(.csv)?

EDIT: Thank you for the answers. My mistake as in my original question I did not provide my actual DF. I have now added this and with the str() result.

@hello_friend this is what is returned when I apply your second solution

```
 game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
1               7                    3                    12
2               7                    3                    12
3              10                    5                    15
4              10                    5                    15
5              12                    6                    17
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Michael. Your columns are not character variables, but factor variables. These behave differently to character variables.

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you I have re-addressed this in the Q! Pretty new to R as you can probably tell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
numeric_df <- setNames(data.frame(lapply(data.frame(
  Vectorize(gsub)(":", ".", DF), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
),
function(x) {
  as.double(x)
})), names(DF))
```

Data:

```
 DF <- structure(list(game.time.total = c("95:09", "95:09", "95:31", 
"95:31", "95:39"), game.time.first.half = c("46:04", "46:04", 
"46:07", "46:07", "46:08"), game.time.second.half = c("49:05", 
"49:05", "49:23", "49:23", "49:31")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for help. My error as I did not supply the actual data I am working and created a separate DF to demonstrate it in my original question. When applying your second solution (Solution 1 didn't work?)- I have added an edit to my original question for further explanation.

Comment: @MichaelD Your question was truncated.

Comment: I have added an edit to my original question, apologies.

Comment: @MichaelD edited please see if this what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the columns to minutes and seconds with the `ms` function from lubridate package.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  mutate_all(ms) %>% 
  mutate_all(period_to_seconds) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean) %>% 
  mutate_all(seconds_to_period)

           game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
1 1H 35M 23.8000000000002S               46M 6S 49M 17.4000000000001S
```

Or without the last `mutate_all` call if you want the mean in seconds.

```
DF %>% 
  mutate_all(ms) %>% 
  mutate_all(period_to_seconds) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)

  game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
1          5723.8                 2766                2957.4
```

**Note:** Asssuming `95.09` means 95 minutes and 9 seconds and not 95 minutes and .09 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful here. Think about the average of `"89:30"` and `"90:30"`. They add to 180 minutes, so the mean should be `90:00`. However, if you convert them to `89.30` and `90.30`, then they add to `179.60` and the mean becomes `89.80`, which doesn't even make sense.

There are packages available that make dealing with time easier, such as `lubridate`, and if you deal with times frequently you should learn to use them. However, the solution below doesn't require any additional packages and is quite straightforward. It defines two small functions to convert between `"mm:ss"` format and number of seconds. You can safely do sums and averages on seconds then convert back to your original format:

```r
as_seconds <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y) * c(60, 1)))

as_min_sec <- function(x) paste0(x %/% 60, sprintf(":%02d", 21))

apply(DF, 2, function(x) as_min_sec(mean(as_seconds(x))))
#>       game.time.total  game.time.first.half game.time.second.half 
#>               "95:21"               "46:21"               "49:21"
```

If you just want to replace the colons with dots in each column, you can do this:

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) gsub(":", ".", x)))
#>   game.time.total game.time.first.half game.time.second.half
#> 1           95.09                46.04                 49.05
#> 2           95.09                46.04                 49.05
#> 3           95.31                46.07                 49.23
#> 4           95.31                46.07                 49.23
#> 5           95.39                46.08                 49.31
```

Comment: Hi Allan, Thanks for the reply. This solution seems to work, thank you! However, this will only help with one part of my analysis. For the next part of my analysis I require the data frame to be in the my suggested layout without any averaging!. You may have seen I have made an edit to my original question which I think should clear things up.

Comment: @MichaelD see my update. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: this didn't change it from a factor variable to a numeric - See hello_friend's solution which seems to have worked. Thank you for your time and advice!

Comment: @MichaelD it wasn't supposed to change it to a numeric. This is very easy to do with a one-liner;  `as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(":", ".", x))))` but that's a really bad idea when dealing with times, for the reasons I outline above.